# Как работает команда RST N микропроцессора i8080?

Tags: ассемблер, intel

Что представляет из себя команда RST N микропроцессора i8080? Как она работает?

Comment: @Manul74 не нужно учить плохому. К тому же качество и полезность текста от ChatGPT - скорее как у художественного текста, а не технического.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/128404/ "i8080 имеет набор из восьми однобайтовых команд RSTn: RST0 — RST7, функционально эквивалентных командам вызова подпрограмм CALL по фиксированным адресам n*8."